# What is the best way to convert this into a integer linear program and what is the best way to solve such a problem?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

I am studying a mixed integer program in the form
$$ \textrm{min}: \sum A x$$ constrained by $\sum x_i = N$

where $x$ is a vector containing only 1's and 0's, N is an integer, and $A$ is a square matrix of real numbers.

What may be the best way/algorithm/solver to solve this class of problem?

Another question I have is how to best convert this into the form required for the MATLAB MILP solver $ \textrm{min}: f^T x$, where $f$ is a vector,as I instead have a sum over a square matrix $A$.

Many thanks for anybody's help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you considered letting $f^{T}$ be the sum of the rows of $A$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I haven't considered this but as far as I can figure out summing the rows of $A$ doesn't give me the same problem (e.g consider a 3x3 matrix $A$ and $x=(1,0,1)$).

Comment: How is the sum calculated in objective function?

Comment: @Bey The objective function first evaluates $Ax$ which returns a vector and then each element of the vector is added together to give a value to minimise. Since $x$ is either 1 or 0, effectively the objective function is the sum of all of the $i$th columns in $A$ for which $x_i=1$

Comment: That is just a compact way to write a linear combination of the values of X — its already linear —not sure what the issue is — are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Bey Thank you for your response. Is there a class of algorithms that this problem lends itself to best for fast solutions? Especially for very large $x$ and where $0<<N<<size(x)$

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to a knapsack problem — but made simpler by the fact that each item has the same weight.

You can actually use a greedy algorithm here:

1. Expand $\sum Ax$ onto a linear objective $\sum_{i=1}^{|x|} a_ix_i$ where $a_i=\sum_{j=1}^{|x|} A_{ji}$
2. Sort $a_i$ in increasing  order
3. Starting from the smallest  $a_i$ set the associated $x_i$ to $1$ until you have set $N$ variables to $1$ (rest are 0).

This will be the optimal solution.

Comment: Actually, not a knapsack problem if there are possibly negative coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I have negative coefficients in $A$. The coefficients are positive along the diagonal and negative or zero everywhere else.

Comment: @testman7 true — but above will still give optimal result — negative value items in knapsack can just be ignored b/c you’ll never select them

Comment: The signs don’t matter here, and you are right that greedy is optimal. But you want increasing order because the objective is minimization.

Comment: @RobPratt correct I was thinking max — should have checked again!!

Comment: min max doesn't matter, just negate A

Comment: @DanielV correct but my answer previously assumed we were maximizing

Comment: FWIW, you probably want a "selection algorithm" like quickselect, rather than sorting.

Comment: @DanielV that works make it quicker :-)